# Change UserControl textbox through Button on Form1

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have form named `Form1` which contains a Button control (`bunifuImageButton9`) and a user control (`UserControl1`). The user control has a textbox (`textBox2`). I need the button to change text in a textbox in the user control.

I know how to change the content in a normal textbox, but I don't see how to access the textbox inside the user control.

How would I do such?

Comment: what do you mean: `but how would I transfer the control between the button on Form1 to UserControl1.`?

Comment: @CodingYoshi Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick and dirty and probably wrong way to do it is to make `textBox2` public instead of private on `UserControl1`, and then from the form, call

```
userControl1.textBox2.Text = "some new value";
```

The more proper way to do this is to add a public property to `UserControl1` that exposes the textbox in a meaningful way:

```
class UserControl1 {
    public string SomeCoolTextValue {
        get {
            return textBox2.Text;
        }
        set {
            textBox2.Text = value;
        }
    }
}

class Form1 {
    private void bunifuImageButton9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        userControl1.SomeCoolTextValue = "some new value";
    }
}
```

Comment: It appears the SomeCoolTextValue string is not transferring to the Form1. An Object reference is required. Should I make UserControl1 u1;

Comment: Ah. I see. Okay. Thanks! I had to change UserControl1 to u1 due to some previous steps I took in my UI.